# Identifying all the names from a given text

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, linguistics, lingpipe

I want to identify all the names written in any text, currently I am using IMDB movie reviews.

I am using stanford POS tagger, and analysing all the proper nouns (as proper noun are names of person,things,places), but this is slow.

Firstly I am tagging all the input lines, then I am checking for all the words with NNP in the end, which is a slow process.

Is there any efficient substitute to achieve this task? ANy library (preferably in JAVA).
Thanks.

Comment: See Apache OpenNLP and research Named Entity Tagging.

Comment: I tried Ipen NLP but results are not so accurate, although it is significantly faster as compared to stanford POS tagger.

Comment: NER is a much harder problem that POS tagging, and a POS tagger won't do what you want. There are of course commercial alternatives for NER, or you could try OpenCalais.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the input language? If yes you could match each word against a dictionnary and flag the word as proper noun if it is not in the dictionnary. It would require a complete dictionnary with all the declensions of each word of the language, and pay attention to numbers and other special cases.

EDIT: See also [this answer in the official FAQ](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/pos-tagger-faq.shtml#h): have you tried to change the model used?

Comment: I know the language, but won't it be even less efficient than what I am doing currently?

Comment: I don't know how the POS tagger works, but I'd guess it also needs to use a dictionary to find out what kind of word it is and identify its role in the sentence. So if you do only the dictionary part it would be quicker. But granted, this is a time-consuming task.

Answer (score 0):

A (paid) web service called GlobalNLP can do it in multiple languages: https://nlp.linguasys.com/docs/services/54131f001c78d802f0f2b28f/operations/5429f9591c78d80a3cd66926